# How to Successfully Load a Static Website with Express.js, Cannot GET /index.html, error

Tags: node.js, linux, express, web

I really don't know what I am doing but I have a simple static website that I am trying to host on a VPS I bought.

My website only has index.html and css files along with some pictures.

I try to deploy this website in 8080 port by using Node.js and Express.js.

I referred to this document here:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/develop-deploy-first-fullstack-web-app/#creatingyourfirstserver

I installed node.js and express.js and created server.js in a folder which is called "public". This folder is also where my website files are located. "index.html" is located here.

I successfully selected the entry point to be server.js.

```
$ ls -l
total 72
drwxr-xr-x  3 debian debian  4096 Apr 18 02:55 Concept
-rw-r--r--  1 debian debian  5081 Apr 18 02:55 index.html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 debian debian   189 Apr 19 11:52 index.js
drwxr-xr-x 52 debian debian  4096 Apr 19 11:43 node_modules
-rw-r--r--  1 debian debian   284 Apr 19 11:43 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 debian debian 31240 Apr 19 11:51 package-lock.json
drwxr-xr-x  4 debian debian  4096 Apr 18 02:55 pictures
-rwxr-xr-x  1 debian debian   202 Apr 18 02:59 server.js
-rw-r--r--  1 debian debian  4621 Apr 18 02:55 styles.css
```

Then inside server.js

```
$ cat server.js
// Load Node modules
var express = require('express');
// Initialize Express
var app = express();
// Render static files
app.use(express.static('public'));
// Port website will run on
app.listen(8080);
```

Then when I do this:

```
$ npm start

> public@1.0.0 start /home/debian/public
> node server.js
```

and then go to browser and type
http://myVpsIP:8080/index.html

it says "Cannot GET /index.html".

Thanks.

Comment: create a folder called public. Put your files in it, and be explicit with your path. Node can be funky when you are not explicit with paths, you may want to try to clear that up with something like express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))

Comment: Thanks!. This one worked like charm...

I changed the section of server.js like this

app.use(express.static('/path/to/folder/public'));

Comment: Fantastic, in the future get used to using __dirname as it is where the node app is running and thus you can refer to sub folders. This allows you to move the app anywhere without breaking the paths.

Answer (score 0):

You told your server to look in the `public` folder for static files, like html, css, and browser-side js. You used this line to do that.

```js
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Your FCC tutorial says this:

> First, move all your website’s static files (HTML, CSS, JS, images, etc.) into a folder called public ...

So do that: create a folder (subdirectory) called `public`, and move index.html, index.js, styles.css, and, I guess, your Pictures folder into it.